# completion of normed vector space in category theory

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, category-theory

How to describe completion of normed vector space in the language of category theory in more general terms? It's mentioned in the nLab page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/completion but how about the detailed proof ?

Below I attached the definition of completion from Klaus Janich's "topology",and similar one can be found in Kreyszig's "introductory functional analysis with applications"

> Now by completion is understood the process of making a non-complete
> space (X, d) into a complete one (Xc, dc) by adjoining as few new
> points as possible:
>
> Definition (Completion). Let (X, d) be a metric space. A metric space
> (Xc, dc) such that X $\in$ Xc is called a completion of (X, d) if
>
> 1. (Xc,dc) is complete, and
> 2. X is dense in Xc

Comment: What nlab page? Without any reference it is hard to understand what specifically you are asking…

Comment: Consider the inclusion functor from complete normed vector spaces to normed vector spaces, both categories equipped with continuous linear  maps. Completion is then the left adjoint to this functor.

Comment: @Lukas: of course one ought to supply a proof that this left adjoint actually exists!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan of course.

Comment: If one considers the problem in the category of uniform spaces and uniformly continuous maps one can indeed apply an adjoint functor theorem to get a left adjoint for the inclusion functor of the subcategory of complete Hausdorff uniform spaces. Note that the category of normed spaces and continuous linear maps does not have infinite products.